Am I correct in this sentence "My interests span different genres"?

My interests span different genres

What I'm trying to say is that I have a lot of interests, but I'm not sure if I use the verb "span" correctly since I read a lot of example sentences and found that "span" mostly goes with a period of time or the length of something that goes from one side to the other.

Choose interest spans or interests span to match subject and verb.

By the way, if by interests you mean anything like hobbies, pastimes, activities, or fields of study, then genres is a poor choice of words. If, on the other hand, you mean things like types of literature (poetry, mystery fiction, biography) or types of music (baroque, jazz, Central-European folk songs), then genres is fine.

The use of the verb span is not limited to describing how certain event lasts through a period of time or how an object is supported across, for example, a canal. It can be used in the OP's example too.
Sense 4 of Collins Dictionary explains:

4 VERB [no passive]
If something spans a range of things, all those things are included in it.
Bernstein's compositions spanned all aspects of music, from symphonies to musicals. [VERB noun]
...a remarkable man whose interests spanned almost every aspect of nature.

